# incremental simulation of GBM

Tags: stochastic-processes, simulation

(I asked [this question in stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774433/python-geometric-brownian-motion-simulation), but I am now thinking my mistake may be mathematical rather than programming).

I am simulating geometric brownian motion, using closed-form solution for the value after an arbitrary (not necessarily infinitesimal) step dt. My drift = 0, standard deviation = 1, initial value = 1.

Of course, the expected value at any future point of such GBM is 1.

But, after 100 steps, I find my GBM process to be in the range between 10^-30 and 10^-15. Typically, it's around 10^-23, and falling consistently. It seems like each step my process tends to fall by a constant factor of around 1.7. If I double my standard deviation, my process falls twice faster (~3.4 times each step).

I'm sure something is wrong with my setup. Here's my Python code, which is nearly readable as pseudocode:

```
import math
import random
p = 1
dt = 1
mu = 0
sigma = 1
for k in range(100): # repeat loop 100 times
    dW = random.normalvariate(0, math.sqrt(dt)) # draw a standard normal random value
    p = p * exp((mu - sigma * sigma / 2) * dt + sigma * dW)
print(p)
```

Thanks...

Edit: I fixed normalvariate to use sqrt(dt) rather than dt * dt. Thanks El Moro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. There is no problem with the code. It's just that the resulting lognormal distribution has enormous scale parameter = 1 *  sqrt(100) = 10. With scale of 10, the skewness is insane.

Thus, even though the mean of the distribution is 1.0, it will take me billions of iterations (if not ***billions of billions***) to see a single number greater than 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Ummm I think your dW should have a standard deviation of sqrt(dt) ( variance of dt not dt*dt).

Comment: Yes... thank you. But since dt = 1, my result is unchanged, and hence the problem remains... :(

Comment: I think you function takes the variance as argument it should be dt instead of dt*dt or sqrt(dt) :). Did you try to see if your normalvariate func works normally? if it gives you independent normal variates ? (because if they happen to be related the algo fails)

Comment: It does take standard deviation, and in any case dt = 1. I also replaced the pseudo random number generator with a true random, with the same result. I just figured out what's wrong though (see my answer below). +1 for fixing my problem with variance.